# How do I dump my data?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I've installed PIG and I'm loading a csv by doing the following:

```
grunt> boys = LOAD '/user/pig_input/student-boys.txt' USING PigStorage ('\t') AS (name:chararray,state:chararray,attendance:float);

2014-07-27 11:54:04,414 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2014-07-27 11:54:04,414 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2014-07-27 11:54:04,525 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2014-07-27 11:54:04,525 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
```

However, when I try to dump the dataset I get the below errors:

```
grunt> DUMP boys;
2014-07-27 11:54:12,710 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias boys
Details at logfile: /home/hduser/tmp/pig_1406476412229.log
```

I tried looking into why this was happening but I'm having trouble understanding the exact reason.

```
grunt> hduser@hadoop:~/tmp$ cat /home/hduser/tmp/pig_1406476412229.log
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias boys

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias boys
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:880)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:774)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:541)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:192)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: Parent path is not a directory: /tmp tmp
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.mkdirs(FSDirectory.java:1464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:2127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.mkdirs(NameNode.java:988)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1478)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1476)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:1258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:504)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1505)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDirectory.create(HDirectory.java:63)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HPath.create(HPath.java:159)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.io.FileLocalizer.getTemporaryPath(FileLocalizer.java:481)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.io.FileLocalizer.getTemporaryPath(FileLocalizer.java:474)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:855)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: Parent path is not a directory: /tmp tmp
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.mkdirs(FSDirectory.java:1464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:2127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.mkdirs(NameNode.java:988)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1478)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1476)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1028)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:198)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:1256)
    ... 19 more
```

I need help understanding why I'm getting these errors? What do I need to change to properly dump the dataset that I loaded?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I installed PIG and try to load a CSV file and dump the data...HOwever when i try to dump the Dataset i get the below errors:  1.org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias boys 2.Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: Parent path is not a directory: /tmp tmp.....PLease help to reoslve the same ...Thanks !

Comment: Where you stored your student-boys.txt file local or HDFS?

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 0):

/user/pig_input/student-boys.txt.

Can you try creating a file with the following lines

boys = LOAD '/user/pig_input/student-boys.txt' USING PigStorage ('\t') AS (name:chararray,state:chararray,attendance:float);

DUMP boys;

Then try to run execute it using pig filename.pig.

Generally grunt mode runs in local mode.

Thanks,

Regards,
Dheeraj Rampally.

Comment: Thanks Dheeraj, As per your suggestion i tried to create a file with .pig extension an tried to run in local mode as pig -x local filename.pig...however im getting the below error now                                                               2014-07-29 06:44:29,175 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2014-07-29 06:44:29,179 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl.addJob(Lorg/apache;

Comment: Hi,Is you run it in local mode then you should be having the local path. I mean the path present on that host.

Answer (score 0):

How did you start the grunt shell? It seems you are in mapreduce mode and the file(s) you want to load are on the local file system.
Either start the grunt shell with
pig -x local
and load the file from the local system 
or 
copy the file(s) you want to load to HDFS and start the shell with
pig

Comment: yes tried both ways and currently when i run in local mode , im getting the error as 2014-07-29 06:44:29,175 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2014-07-29 06:44:29,179 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl.addJob(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/jobcontrol/Job;)Ljava/lang/String;